# Error in android studio 3: OpenGL backend 'angle' without OpenGL ES 1.x library detected. Using GLESv2 only

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Each time I run an Android project in Android Studio version 3 on emulator, I get the following error in Event log:

```
Emulator : OpenGL backend 'angle' without OpenGL ES 1.x library detected. Using GLESv2 only.
```

All projects works fine as should, however i keep receiving this error.
The emulator which i choose is Nexus 5 API 27.
What could be the problem?

Thanks.